# Redux store: proxy-memoize does not cache properly

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit

Redux now kind of [recommend](https://redux.js.org/usage/deriving-data-selectors#proxy-memoize) the usage of proxy-memoize to memoize the store. So I tried this library, but my components that use it are redrawn even if the content does not change. Right now, my store is basically a list of objects with multiple properties, say `name` and `value`: when I do:

```
const allEtags = useSelector(selectAllEtags);
```

I wish to get the list of all `name`, so I defined `selectAllEtags` as:

```
// Returns the etags coming from the columns
export const selectEtagsColumns = memoize(state =>
  state.stateToSave.allSchedules.map(sch => sch.columns.map(col => col.field)).flat(1).map(e => {return {key: e, label: e, labelShort: e}})
)

// Get etag constraints
export const selectEtagsConstraints = memoize((state) => state.constraints.etagsConstraints);

// Returns the etags created by the user
export const selectEtagsUser = memoize(state =>
  selectEtagsConstraints(state).map(c => c.name).filter(e => e).map(e => {return {key: e, label: e, labelShort: e}})
);

export const selectAllEtags = memoize(state =>
  [...hardcodedEtags, ...selectEtagsColumns(state), ...selectEtagsUser(state)]
);
```

However, if a `value` is changed by calling the redux reducer:

```
    updateEtagsConstraint(state, action) {
      const {id, constraint} = action.payload;
      state.etagsConstraints[id] = {...state.etagsConstraints[id], ...constraint};
    },
```

then the cache is invalidated and the component is redrawn. Is it me doing something wrong, proxy-memoize that is not supposed to work on this usecase? If not, what is the recommended way to solve this issue?

Comment: Not sure what the question is, since you have this memo functions that depend on state, if state change they recalculate…

Comment: Basically map does always new reference, so it’s impossible properly depend on it result

Comment: @antokhio well all selectors depend on state, but proxy-memoize was supposed to be a bit clever than other libraries to do this comparison using ES6 proxy etc… This use case seems to be supported in, e.g., the code presented in https://redux.js.org/usage/deriving-data-selectors#proxy-memoize (they are even using map) so I’m surprised to see that this does not get memoized in my example.

Comment: @antokhio so I have no other choice than relying on https://github.com/reduxjs/reselect#customize-equalitycheck-for-defaultmemoize ?

Comment: i’ve would look here https://github.com/reduxjs/reselect/releases/tag/v5.0.0-alpha.1